# Can I adjust an audio file volume in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing a program that plays two audio files automatically, but one file is much louder than the other one so I want to make them both have the same volume. I tried setVolume(float left volume, right volume) but it didn't work.

Note: the user doesn't control the volume himself

Comment: You can use "setVolume()" if you are using either AudioTrack or MediaPlayer.

Comment: @DavidLee I tried but didn't work